# How to notify running thread for new change

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, android-activity, thread-safety

I have made one simple demo by implementing Thread and Handler. On onResume() Background thread will create and start if its not yet started.

Problem: On theme change, activity get destroyed and re-create, but background running task will remain continue.

Here My thread updating UI(like set current time in TextView) on each 1 sec.

UI was getting update before activity re-created.

According to my observation on re-creation of activity, thread doesn't have new instance of activity. Means my thread is running with the old copy of activity.

So any changes on latest activity's data member will not affect to thread.

How to give current instance of activity to thread?

Comment: Device theme. On theme change, activity will not destroyed immediate but when you open app at that time it will.

Comment: But i dont want to kill, as some portion of task is completed. If i kill thread then whole process have to start  from beginning.

Comment: Leave it. I think you dont know the solution. You must read Thread management.